# OTA upgrade from older NodeMCU

Tags: lua, nodemcu

I'm hoping to find a way to update to the next NodeMCU version OTA as many of my devices are rather difficult to access.

To do this (if I'm headed in the right direction) I'd need a way to add binary C functions at runtime.  I'm picturing using LUA to upload a binary file containing some C functions to call the system flash operations.  Then using those in an LUA OTA update program based on the Arduino version of the firmware Update class.

I believe this would mean loading binaries into RAM or pointing to a binary file in SPIFFS.

My question is, are the necessary functions needed to manipulate the LUA function table to add C functions available in LUA at runtime?  Can they be pointed to wherever I put the binaries?  Is the C compiler output relocatable?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could read these guidelines before asking a new question. Thanks.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks, I did read them. Did I miss something in guidelines?

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/1496

Comment: Thanks Marcel - I wasn't sure whether to discuss here or as a feature request on the nodemcu GIT.

Comment: The decider for me was that this isn't a feature request for the new nodemcu version.  I'm looking for a way to upgrade old versions to the new version without needing to physically flash.  If I can upload a binary file with C functions to get at the SDK APIs and call them from LUA directly I might be able to get it working remotely.

Comment: I'm glad this isn't possible; would be a huge security problem.

Comment: Yes, but not any worse than OTA and you're adding that to the next version of NodeMCU, right? 

Without this feature we need to pull our devices to upgrade to a version with OTA which gives one an opportunity to rethink the entire approach.

Comment: "not any worse than OTA" - not at all (unless I'm still not getting your case). The first and most important line of defense is that your devices don't accept any incoming connections; let alone those which would make it run arbitrary C code. If OTA then it's the device that, based on some indicator, pulls an update from a trusted source. "you're adding that to the next version of NodeMCU, right" - we never make any promises.

Comment: No, my intention was not automatic, it would be deliberate by the device owner:  Upload an LUA file and a binary (from a trusted source), restart the device to run it.  Would this be more appropriate as a feature discussion on GIT (even if the idea would be to use it for earlier versions of NodeMCU with the assumption (right, no promises) the next version will already have OTA)?